# cant understand about the error of storing accelerometer data in json file using kivy

Tags: json, python-2.7, kivy

In the following code, i followed instructions according to docoumentation of kivy stroing data into json file. i am getting error about directory. i am fresher and i am stuck from past days.Help me with this.

```
__version__ = '1.0' #declare the app version. Will be used by buildozer


from kivy.app import App #for the main app
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout #the UI layout
from kivy.uix.label import Label #a label to show information
from plyer import accelerometer #object to read the accelerometer
from kivy.clock import Clock #clock to schedule a method
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from os.path import join

class UI(FloatLayout):#the app ui
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lblAcce = Label(text="Accelerometer: ") #create a label at the                   center
        self.add_widget(self.lblAcce) #add the label at the screen

        try:

            accelerometer.enable() #enable the accelerometer
            # if you want do disable it, just run: accelerometer.disable()
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 2.0/1) #24 calls per second
        except:
            self.lblAcce.text = "Failed to start accelerometer" #error
    
    def update(self, dt):
        txt = ""
        try:
            txt = "Accelerometer:\nX = %.2f\nY = %.2f\nZ = %2.f " %(
              accelerometer.acceleration[0], #read the X value
              accelerometer.acceleration[1], # Y
              accelerometer.acceleration[2]) # Z

            data_dir = getattr(self, '/storage/emulated/0/') #get a writable path to save the file
            store = JsonStore(join(data_dir, 'user.json'))   

            store.put('x',accelerometer.acceleration[0])
            store.put('y',accelerometer.acceleration[1])
            store.put('z',accelerometer.acceleration[2])
        except:
            txt = "Cannot read accelerometer!" #error
        self.lblAcce.text = txt #add the correct text 

class Accelerometer(App): #our app
    def build(self):
        ui = UI()# create the UI
        return ui #show it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Accelerometer().run() #start our app
```

Comment: Can you add the error to the question?

Comment: File "main.py", line 28
    data_dir = getattr(self, '/storage/emulated/0/') #get a writable path to save the file
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent@EL3PHANTEN

Comment: Oh okey in that case, you have to fix your indentation. I edited your question to get the indentation right. Sometimes when ppl post questions, they get the indentation wrong. Aparantly in your case, it was wrong in your code. Try the code in your question now.

Comment: @AbdulRehman please add the error to the question.

Comment: @Al.G. above comment is showing error. when i run my code with "buildozer -v android debug" command it builds but when i run apk in android it crashes.

Comment: when i run with python main.py it shows the above error

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN same error.

Comment: Okey. well fix the indentation. Thats what the error say is wrong. Check that you only use tabs or only use spaces. Dont mix those

Comment: maybe put the ( that is right after % on the line below. So it looks like this: `(accelerometer.acceleration[0],`

Comment: still getting error. @EL3PHANTEN can u run this code?

Comment: i tried other way to store but it is still giving indent error.@EL3PHANTEN

Comment: Yes, I dont get the indentation error

Comment: @el3ien **please do not** edit questions in a way that fixes a problem - i.e., if the question is about an `IndentationError`, don't fix the indentation. The purpose of questions is to showcase a problem for the sake of future visitors. This is **not a discussion forum, nor a help desk**; the goal is not to resolve OP's problem by any means the site software allows, but to *create a useful Q&A pair, and only when appropriate* (generic questions about `IndentationError` are almost always duplicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my update function, i was passing wrong arrguemnts to json store.

```
jsonStore=('/storage/emulated/0/hello.json')
```

this is the way to pass path of your android device to json store

```
json.put('a')
```

it will put this character in hello.json in internal storage of your android mobile.